# scrolling horizontal bar of certain value?

Tags: c#, scrollbar, sendmessage, custom-lists

I have this code (edit box is a text box) 
The purpose of the code is that if i have focus in one of the dinamic text box of list view if  i press tab i need to pass to the successive text box. But i also have to scroll the bar else i can't see the textbox, i need to scroll the bar by text box widht but this code doens't work.) :

```
                 static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
                   SendMessage(base.Handle, (uint)WM_HSCROLL, (System.UIntPtr)editBox.Width, (System.IntPtr)1);
```

But doesn't work, only work with  (System.UIntPtr)ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement or other proprieter of ScrollEventType, but the value of these is not visible.
How can I pass an integer and move the scroll bar horizontal how i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the listview into a Panel, and use the panel's [ScrollControlIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scrollcontrolintoview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to scroll the textbox into view.